# Creating Gem configuration file in YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml, configuration-files

I am just barely beginning my journey with Ruby. For my internship right now I am trying to use a web scraper from github written in Ruby.  I have successfully installed Ruby and the scraper Gem, now I am at the part of the installation instructions that read like so:

> Create configuration file at ~/.googleplay_dev_scraper, or ./.googleplay_dev_scraper in YAML format.

My questions are very very basic.  How and where do I create this file? I basically need a step by step instruction on what exactly I need to be doing but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Here is the github repository for reference: https://github.com/tmurakam/googleplay_dev_scraper

Comment: You need to learn unix/linux *basics* and learn about `YAML`. Also please specify which operating system you are using.

Comment: @TamerShlash  I do have some familiarity working in the shell, the part I'm a complete beginner is Ruby itself. I will read up on YAML.  And I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: `~` is an abbreviation for the root directory of your user, it's the same one which contains the Desktop, Photos, Music, etc. folders.

Comment: @maxpleaner Great thank you.  Is the instruction telling me to have a file in that root directory called like ".googleplay_dev_scraper.yml" or is it telling me to create a configuration file inside ANOTHER directory called ".googleplay_dev_scraper". Thank you for your help!